# How to pass the class type

Tags: android, class, casting

I am trying to remake one library.I need to pass the class type to another object, and then cast variable to this type. I trying something like that

```
public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    Class<? extends Application> appClass;

    public void setAppClass(Class<? extends Application> c) {
        appClass = c;
    }

    protected SocialProviderManager getSocialProviderManager() {
        return ((appClass) getApplication()).getSocialProviderManager();
    }
}
```

Another class will

```
public class GameApplication extends Application {

        private SocialProviderManager socialProviderManager;

        public SocialProvideManager getSocialProviderManager()
        {
            return socialProviderManager
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            BaseActivity.setAppClass(this);

        }
    }
```

How to make this construction work. Thanks.

Comment: it doesn't work.First problem - couldn't cast to this type, second - couldn't find method `getSocialProviderManager()`.

Comment: If you substitute ? with T then you instead off (appClass) you can have T. Right?

Comment: `Class<T extends Application> appClass` what wrong with this code? Syntax error on token "extends", , expected

Comment: What is `SocialProviderManager`?  Why are you using generics for the appClass?  Your questions shows no understanding of Java, generics, or Android.

Comment: `SocialProviderManager` is a class fron my project. I use it cause appClass may be any type.